# Scorm player issue

Tags: php, scorm

I think I get me in a real trouble, because I am working on a LMS.

Actually I need to develop an LMS, a simple one.

My big problem is the Scorm.

I am developing in PHP, and what I want that if I upload the scorm 1.2 course, to be able to track the course.
Or even simpler I need to get the status(if is passed, or incomplete), score, and time.

Any suggestion, links, resources, examples?

Please, help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is such a thing as a 'simple' LMS, where SCORM is concerned.

It is hard, but it is possible.

The specification for SCORM 1.2 is here -

http://www.adlnet.gov/resources/SCORM-1-2-Specification?type=technical_documentation

It's big, and detailed, and covers everything you need to provide for SCORM 1.2.

However, if you just want something up and running quickly, have a look at some other LMSs that have already been built.  There are loads out there, both free and paid.

For an example of how an LMS works, check out http://cloud.scorm.com/, you can play around with it there, and see how it handles things.